# How to redirect the console output into the GUI console view using eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I m doing a project using eclipse plugins in jave to create an ide like eclipse that runs vue scripts.Presently this programs are executed in console.I have created a GUI to write these program,when i press the run button in my GUI,I need to get back the output to my GUI Console view after running is completed.

How shall i do this?Can anyone help me in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you starting the programs? If you use `Runtime.exec()`, as a result you get a `Process`. You can call `Process.getOutputStream()` to get hold of the output stream of spawned process, and then read lines from it and output them to your GUI console view.

Comment: i m not using Runtime.exec,i m creating a connection to the server and then passing the command to run the program...the output is being displayed in the eclipse console,but i need to display it in the GUI console...I m not creating a process here..So how shall i do this